# Modifying data in mysql table using phphmyadmin

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I want to add relative path [images/abook] before the example.jpg in column image of table abook I am using MySQL phpmyadmin. I want to add this path in 180 records. What is the way to achieve this.

Comment: In the SQL-tab you could use (if your image-column is named imageUrl) `UPDATE images SET imageUrl = 'images/abook/' + imageUrl`

Comment: `UPDATE abook 
    SET image = 'images/abook/example.jpg'
    WHERE image = 'example.jpg'`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use plain sql for your purpose

```
UPDATE abook SET image=CONCAT('images/abook/',image);
```

If you are looking to do it for rows that match a specific criteria, you should use a where clause

Comment: I'd add a slash after `abook`.

Comment: I tried UPDATE  `mrizwan`.`abbook` SET  `image` =CONCAT('images/abook/' , image) WHERE  image = '*.jpg'; but it is not working. Kindly correct me. Thanks

Comment: try using
UPDATE mrizwan.abbook SET image =CONCAT('images/abook/' , image) WHERE image like '%.jpg';